# Calling an Object (not a Key) via a variable that then allows accessing its keys

Tags: javascript

I like how you can do this

EXTERNAL JS FILE

```
var sword = {
damage: 10
};
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="swingWeapon.call(sword)">Swing Weapon</button>
```

2nd EXTERNAL JS FILE

```
function swingWeapon() {
    document.getElementById("damage_box").innerHTML = this.damage;
};

//Returns 10 as expected
```

...

But is there a way I could do this?

EXTERNAL JS FILE

```
var sword = {
damage: 10
};

var spear = {
damage: 8
};

var dagger = {
damage: 6
};

var equippedWeapon = spear;
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="swingWeapon.call(equippedWeapon)">Swing Weapon</button>
```

2nd EXTERNAL JS FILE

```
function swingWeapon() {
    document.getElementById("damage_box").innerHTML = this.damage;
};

//Expected 8, but Returns undefined / Unable to get property errors
```

Please keep in mind I am using external javascript files for this. Any insight appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have an HTML file where `damage_box` is defined as the `id` of some element?

Comment: As long as your external files are loaded correctly your code as shown should work: [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1OwS8zwWBB8z0yCTRzmb?p=preview). I would go back and check spelling mistakes, loading issues

Comment: what problem are you facing when using equippedWeapon?

Comment: @Paul Yes. The first example returns "10" as expected/mentioned.

Comment: SOLVED: In my own code I was setting `var equippedWeapon = spear;` **above** the objects instead of below them. Thank you @PatrickEvans for the working demo that made me realize this.